# why does android emulator increase the RAM size automatically and make me fail to launch it?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm using win7. To launch android emulator successfully, i set the RAM size 512MB in AVD manager. but when i launch the android emulator, it told me "WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB" and "Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument". Why does it increase the RAM size? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem.
I created a virtual device of API level 23.Then it gives me the error as yours.

**Solution:**

I download and install Android sdk for API level 19 from SDK manager(SDK Platforms,SDK Tools).
Then deleted my existing emulator device(api 23) and  after downloading system image for i.e. kitkat (api 19) that takes lower memory create a new AVD.

[image: system image download]

Then Running this one solved the error "Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument". It runs smoothly in my win7

Answer (score 1):

Probably its a requirement of the Android version that you are running.

RAM mimimun is dependent on architecture (32/64 bits) and screen size.

More info about this can be found [here](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/es//compatibility/5.0/android-5.0-cdd.pdf) especifically section 7.6 memory and storage.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Increase RAM Size for Your Android Studio from `512 MB` to `1 GB` or `Create new AVD Emulator` with low version API (`Ex: API 19, Kitkat`).

Answer (score -2):

I search many times for emulator error but every time i found the error emulator not working increase the RAM size...I increase mn RAM 1GB and now its work....try this